# How to use SSML in a Twilio Autopilot Say action

Tags: twilio

The Twilio documentation indicates that either plain text or SSML can be used in a say action:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/say

However when I've tried to use SSML, as below, it skips over whatever SSML is there. No errors are thrown, but behavior is not as expected.

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "say": {
                "speech": "<break time='1s'/> Hello <break time='1s'/> World!"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In another odd scenario, wrapping a word with an  tag causes the word to be said after the rest of the sentence has been said.

Anyone successfully used SSML in this way? I really just need it for the break tag since Autopilot doesn't support Pause.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an issue, based on the product documentation, and the current functionality you are seeing. I suggest opening a support ticket with Twilio support. You can do so from within the Twilio console, in the upper right corner, under the ? icon.

Say (Action)

https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/say